# mysql batchUpdate limit

Tags: java, spring, batch-updates

Is there any maximum record limit for `batchUpdate()` function in `SimpleJdbcTemplate`. Link [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcTemplate.html).

I need to insert around 100,000 record at a time.Presently I am getting timeout in the following line

```
MapSqlParameterSource[] batchArgs = batchArguements.toArray(new MapSqlParameterSource[0]);
simpleJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(SQL_INSERT, batchArgs);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you need to insert them in one transaction, or can you split the insert into several transactions?

Comment: presently I am trying to insert it in single transaction.but its getting the timeout.Is their is anyway to insert it in single transaction?

Comment: could that be a "max_allowed_packet" issue, i wonder.

Comment: May be this would be of help - http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?39,28504

Comment: @Sajith try modifying "wait_timout" server variable, and test again- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout

Answer (score -1):

This is the class we use. See Javadoc for explanation:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import com.google.common.base.Function;

/**
 * Performs a MySQL bulk insert.
 * <p>
 * A MySQL bulk insert statement allows for performing multiple insertions with
 * one insert statement:
 * 
 * <pre>
 *     INSERT INTO tbl (col1, col2, ..., colN) VALUES
 *        (val1.1, val1.2, ..., val1.N),
 *        (val2.1, val2.2, ..., val2.N),
 *           ...,
 *        (valM.1, valM.2, ..., valM.N);
 * </pre>
 * </p>
 * 
 * @param <T> the entity type to work on.
 */
public class MySqlBulkInsert<T extends Object> {
  private final EntityManager entityManager;
  private final String tableName;

  /**
   * Constructor.
   * 
   * @param entityManager the entity manager
   * @param tableName the name of the table
   */
  public MySqlBulkInsert(final EntityManager entityManager, final String tableName) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
    this.tableName = tableName;
  }

  /**
   * Executes the bulk insert.
   * 
   * @param entities the entities to insert
   * @param csvColumns the columns to insert as a comma separated values string
   * @param entityToValuesFunction the entity to values function.
   * Please note: Values have to be correct formatted. For example String values
   * must contain apostrophes.
   * @return the number of records inserted
   */
  public int execute(List<T> entities,
      String csvColumns,
      Function<T, Object[]> entityToValuesFunction) {
    return execute(entities, csvColumns.split("\\s*,\\s*"), entityToValuesFunction);
  }

  /**
   * Executes the bulk insert.
   * 
   * @param entities the entities to insert
   * @param columns the columns to insert
   * @param entityToValuesFunction the entity to values function
   * Please note: Values have to be correct formatted. For example String values
   * must contain apostrophes.
   * @return the number of records inserted
   */
  public int execute(List<T> entities,
      String[] columns,
      Function<T, Object[]> entityToValuesFunction) {
    if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(entities)) {
      return 0;
    }

    final StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    sql.append("insert into ");
    sql.append(tableName);
    sql.append(" (");
    sql.append(StringUtils.join(columns, ','));
    sql.append(") values ");
    List<String> records = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (T entity : entities) {
      Object[] values = entityToValuesFunction.apply(entity);
      String csvValues = StringUtils.join(values, ',');
      if (columns.length != values.length) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Number of values doesn't match number of columns ("
            + columns.length + "): " + csvValues);
      }
      records.add("(" + csvValues + ")");
    }
    sql.append(StringUtils.join(records, ','));
    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql.toString());
    return query.executeUpdate();
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is not JDBC, does not fix the problem, and even for JPA is a little wacky.

Comment: @AdamGent, care to elaborate? The OP asked for a solution for MySQL - I provided one. The class is called _MySql_BulkInsert for a reason. How can it not be JDBC if it's JPA? There's nothing wacky about it, it uses an SQL-feature MySQL supports.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.is it insert in single transaction?in this code what this entityManager class doing? Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql.toString());